# XSLT 1.0: Counting number of matched block and create Map

Tags: dictionary, xslt-1.0, counter

I have searched across, found that variables are immutable ( constants) in XSLT. 
I have two questions.
Sample input xml is given .

```
<employees>
    <!-- Block1 -->
    <employee>
        <id>123</id>
        <name>steve</name>
        <work>developer</work>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <id>444</id>
        <name>mark</name>
        <work>developer</work>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <id>444</id>
        <name>alex</name>
        <work>tester</work>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <id>555</id>
        <name>john</name>
        <work>architect</work>
    </employee>
    <!-- Block 2-->
    <projects>
        <project>
            <pid>p2</pid>
            <roles>
                <role>developer</role>
                <role>tester</role>
            </roles>
            <total>30</total>
        </project>
        <project>
            <pid>p4</pid>
            <roles>
                <role>tester</role>
            </roles>
            <total>3</total>
        </project>
        <project>
            <pid>p3</pid>
            <roles>
                <role>architect</role>
            </roles>
            <total>2</total>
        </project>
    </projects>
</employees>
```

output :

Scenario (Ques) : 2

Part of :

```
<Projects>
        <pid>p2</pid>
        <employees>
            <empName>steve</empName>
            <empName>mark</empName>
            <empName>alex</empName>
        </employees>
    </Projects>

Not Part of : 

<Projects>
        <pid>p2</pid>
        <employees-exclude>
            <empName>john</empName>
        </employees-exclude>
    </Projects>
```

Scenario (Ques) :3

```
<Projects>
    <pid>p2</pid>
    <empList>
        <emp>
            <resource>1</resource>
            <!-- like GUID , unique, increment  starts from '1'-->
            <empName>steve</empName>
        </emp>
        <emp>
            <resource>2</resource>
            <!-- like GUID , unique-->
            <empName>mark</empName>
        </emp>
        <emp>
           <resource>3</resource>
           <!-- like GUID , unique-->
           <empName>alex</empName>
       </emp>
    </empList>
</Projects>
```

Questions:

1. Can I create a map which maintains all employee details . (Key would be 'work' and value would be list of id+name),  is it possible?
   output : I want to prepare the emp list based on  project id. there is a logic around. so, I have to prepare a list ahead of.
2. For the given project id (pid), I want to get all the employees who are selected based on work(from Block1) based on role (Block2), and who are not part of it? Input would be 
   Output:
3. To count number of entries matched ? we have'position()'  which tells that the current iteration in for loop. but I want only matched block. 
   Example, if there are 3 employess matched out of 6. I need the value to appended like,  resource+unique-Id. unique-id starts from '1'.
   Output:

Much appreciated your help and support.

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. It would be helpful to see the expected result of transforming the given example. In general, you can use a **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key)** to fetch the eligible employees from the context of a project (or a role). I am not sure what you mean by "not part of it".

Comment: @Michel, I edited my question, added expected output .  Thanks a lot,

Comment: Where is the "input" (`p2`) coming from? And why is `alex` excluded from the result in Scenario 3?

Comment: input  is from pid element, thats my requirements, based on some condition I have to select 'p2'.  Yes,  alex should be there in Scenrio3. I edited it. Thanks.

Comment: "*based on some condition I have to select 'p2'.*" I am afraid that doesn't tell me anything. You speak of "*the given project id*", but there's is no "given" project id in your input: all the projects are equally given.

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of moving this forward, try this as your starting point:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="emp-by-work" match="employee" use="work" />

<xsl:template match="/employees">
    <projects>
        <xsl:for-each select="projects/project">
            <xsl:variable name="emp-include" select="key('emp-by-work', roles/role)" />
            <project>
                <xsl:copy-of select="pid"/>
                 <empList>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$emp-include">
                        <emp>
                            <resource>
                                <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                            </resource>
                            <empName>
                                <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                            </empName>
                        </emp>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                 </empList>
            </project>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </projects>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This returns a numbered list of eligible employees for every project - similar to your #3 scenario:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projects>
  <project>
    <pid>p2</pid>
    <empList>
      <emp>
        <resource>1</resource>
        <empName>steve</empName>
      </emp>
      <emp>
        <resource>2</resource>
        <empName>mark</empName>
      </emp>
      <emp>
        <resource>3</resource>
        <empName>alex</empName>
      </emp>
    </empList>
  </project>
  <project>
    <pid>p4</pid>
    <empList>
      <emp>
        <resource>1</resource>
        <empName>alex</empName>
      </emp>
    </empList>
  </project>
  <project>
    <pid>p3</pid>
    <empList>
      <emp>
        <resource>1</resource>
        <empName>john</empName>
      </emp>
    </empList>
  </project>
</projects>
```

---

To list the excluded employees, you could do something like this (unfortunately, there's no "negative" key):

```
<xsl:template match="/employees">
    <projects>
        <xsl:for-each select="projects/project">
            <project>
                <xsl:copy-of select="pid"/>
                 <employees-exclude>
                    <xsl:for-each select="/employees/employee[not(work = current()/roles/role)]">
                        <emp>
                            <empName>
                                <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                            </empName>
                        </emp>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                 </employees-exclude>
            </project>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </projects>
</xsl:template>
```

to return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projects>
  <project>
    <pid>p2</pid>
    <employees-exclude>
      <emp>
        <empName>john</empName>
      </emp>
    </employees-exclude>
  </project>
  <project>
    <pid>p4</pid>
    <employees-exclude>
      <emp>
        <empName>steve</empName>
      </emp>
      <emp>
        <empName>mark</empName>
      </emp>
      <emp>
        <empName>john</empName>
      </emp>
    </employees-exclude>
  </project>
  <project>
    <pid>p3</pid>
    <employees-exclude>
      <emp>
        <empName>steve</empName>
      </emp>
      <emp>
        <empName>mark</empName>
      </emp>
      <emp>
        <empName>alex</empName>
      </emp>
    </employees-exclude>
  </project>
</projects>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael.